# XGBoost latency spikes during inference

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, xgboost

I am having the following problem: a deploye python service (Kubernetes using Docker) containing a XGB model stalls and leads to large latencies (>1sec) - however this behaviour can't be reproduced locally running the service on a MacbookPro 2018.

Detailed description: I have a python service which is running a XGB model on every call. When initializing the service I load the trained models into a dictionary from where the models can then be accessed during a predict. The models are trained using the Learning API and stored as JSON files (trained with version 1.3.3). The predict code is implemented something like this:

```
#Touchdown
td_clf = models['drive_outcome']['touchdown']
td_prob_bin = td_clf.predict(DMatrix(to_predict[:, :-1]))
td_prob = float(td_prob_bin)
```

Throughout the service there are multiple other XGB models being used in a similar manner and generally the predict latency is around 5ms for the whole service. The problem arises when this service is deployed to a Kubernetes cluster to perform predictions in real time. The service is packaged within the following docker:

```
FROM python:3.9.6-slim-buster

EXPOSE 6001
WORKDIR /american_football

ENV PYTHONPATH=..
ARG arg_league
ENV LEAGUE=$arg_league

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN pip install 'xgboost==1.3.3' 'numpy==1.20.3' grpcio-tools graypy requests
```

This docker image is being deployed to a Kubernetes cluster running AWS machines with amd64 architecture. The latencies detected were first measured using Grafana and later verified using cProfile (default timer) and logging the time spent to execute the service.

The weird points are:

- this only occurs in the service running XGB, other services which run
  solely numpy do not suffer from these latencies, although they are
  all running on the same nodes within the cluster
- this is not the first request (so its not an initialization issue),
  but any random request after a given pod excecuting the service had
  already responded to multiple previous requests with low latency
- locally I have not managed to replicate this issue (same python and
  xgboost versions)
- the profiler reports the time being spent in xgb.core functions:

  1126 function calls (1102 primitive calls) in 1.337 seconds

  ```
  Ordered by: internal time

  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       8    0.685    0.086    0.686    0.086 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/data.py:132(_from_numpy_array)
       8    0.647    0.081    0.648    0.081 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:1385(predict)
       1    0.000    0.000    1.337    1.337 /american_football/model_services/predict_states/predict_states_model.py:28(predict_states)
       8    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:192(ctypes2numpy)
       8    0.000    0.000    0.686    0.086 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:435(__init__)
      33    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
       2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:138(unique)
       9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /american_football/model_services/predict_states/predict_states_model.py:297(construct_lookup_state)
       2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py:310(_unique1d)
      16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py:249(__init__)
  ```

I don't know if anybody has some tips to what I could try? Improve the profiling somehow to determine what is happening? The service has one worker, two designated CPUs in the cluster and I have already tried limiting the nthread of the os to 1.
Maybe somebody has an idea? Thanks for reading this wall.